# Media query not working in one environment, but working in another

Tags: css, less, media-queries

I have a LESS environment that is bringing together multiple files and putting everything together into a massive .CSS file (forced to work this way).

However, in one environment the "@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)" declaration is being validated and the custom CSS for it is rendering properly in all instances.  However, in another environment with the exact same media query and CSS, it is not even acknowledging it within the CSS file.

**Working environment:** giving.massgeneral.org

[CSS^] https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hxtevg0ft0hsae/base.css

**Non-working environment:** secure.massgeneral.org/bootstrap-library

[CSS^] https://www.dropbox.com/s/ncrbgxs2ot184cm/bbnc.css

The most notable issue is the following query that is completely being ignored in the "secure." environment:

```
// Tablets & small desktops only
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { 
    // Hide everything else
    .hidden-desktop    { display: inherit !important; }
    .visible-desktop   { display: none !important; }

    // Show
    .visible-tablet    { display: inherit !important; }

    // Hide
    .hidden-tablet     { display: none !important; }
}
```

It is successfully generating this code and placing it into the "bbnc.css" file, however, it is not associating the styles with the classes above when in the viewport designated in the "secure." environment.

Any advice outside would be greatly appreciate on getting this to validate.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it -- and if your going to do that, at least post the link to the css files so we dont have to go dig them up.

Comment: it's also a lot more difficult looking at minified css - it might be a good idea to ensure that all of the css is unobfuscated and identical between both pages (I honestly can't tell as they're both fairly complicated, and I don't have enough time to determine what exactly is different between two minified stylesheets). You can only really compare the two pages if you're sure they're pulling the same css, otherwise the comparison is irrelevant.

Comment: Updated the original post with links to the CSS files.  My main focus is on the media query "@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)".  Everything in these brackets are not registering in the secure.massgeneral.org environment.

Comment: If I change them to "@media (max-width: 979px)", all the CSS works properly, but I do not want to change all the instances and possibly break it in both environments.  My goal is to not only resolve the issue, but figure out why it works in one environment but not the other.

Comment: Have you tried "@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)" instead of "@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)"?

Comment: I have Sean, still no dice.  It seems to have an issue with any media query that has two screen widths targeted (min and max).

Comment: have you got the media query stylesheet loaded last? Other styles might be overiding the media queries (they may not be the actual problem, you might need to look elsewhere)

Comment: It's loaded the exact way that the "giving." environment loads it. I've also tried loading it at the very end of the less import file with no avail.  It is literally occurring on all instances of media queries that have a min-width and a max-width set.

Everything was working in the "secure." environment, then we upgraded the CMS we're using (which in turn upgraded the doctype to HTML5) and caused all the media queries in question to no longer validate.

Comment: have you tried reverting the doctype then? It's probably best to try and discern what's different between the working and not working pages, that'll be the easiest way (I know I'm almost definitely stating the obvious there!)

Comment: Unfortunately, the CMS my client is using does not permit core modifying of the code (which includes the doctype).